# Can't add any apt repository due to issues with python3

Tags: ubuntu, apt, python3

i am trying to add an apt repository, but i get an error saying:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 68, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi.repository'
```

my python version is 3.8.2, same as the apt package version.

tried to:

change the shebang in /usr/bin/add-apt-repository from #!/usr/bin/python3 to #!/usr/bin/python3.8

install pygobject with pip, but `python3.8 -m pip install gobject PyGObject` says "requirement already satisfied"

But the problem never gets solved

if you could help me, it would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same Problem after upgrading to python3.8

simply solved it by reinstalling the python3-gi module

```
sudo apt install python3-gi --reinstall
```